# Get a timestamp from a day,year, and month

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have the following string: 2013-03-22

I need to convert that to a UNIX Timestamp.

How do I do this using PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I agreed with @zdhickman..you just go through this link:http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function of PHP.

Like

```
$unixstamp = strtotime("2013-03-22");
```

Answer (score 2):

With [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-03-22');
$dateTime->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple:**

```
echo $time = strtotime("2013-03-22");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

`strtotime("2013-03-22")`

It will convert the date sting into **timestamp** value.